# Does the video game Control (2019) depict a real computer system? What is it?

Tags: gaming, identify-this-computer, dec

I was playing Remedy Entertainment's video game *[Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_(video_game))* the other day. Inside the game world, I've come across several computers. (They all look extremely similar.) To me, it looks like some kind of DEC system. Now I'm wondering... is it just designed *in the style of* a DEC? Or is it an *actual* real-world model? And if so, which one? Perhaps someone more familiar with this stuff can tell me...

[image]

Comment: Which game is it? I suppose it's not an issue to be mentioned.

Comment: @Krackout It really should be mentioned in order to properly attribute the screenshot, but searching for the "Cleanse the Benicoff TV" reveals that the game is "Control" by Remedy Entertainment.

Comment: @RossRidge Yep, it's definitely Control. I guess I should have said that...

Comment: This looks exactly like the Horoscope computers that used to be at our state fair.  They were totally fake of course, with blinking lights provided just for effect.  The actual computer was probably the cheapest and smallest thing they could find with a random number generator, hidden away somewhere.

Comment: The Tek 503(?) vacuum tube scopes on the right look pretty real.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### TL;DR:

> Is this a real system? Which one?

No, it's most likely not a specific machine but a setup to look contemporary.

---

### In Detail:

> I've come across several computers. (They all look extremely similar.)

The usual way of game designers to speed up development: Reuse of props.

> [or] is it just designed in the style of a DEC

That seems to be the purpose. All elements are at least smoothed or outright edited/recreated.

> Or is it an actual real-world model?

Nop. Even if these were real components, they would be quite unusual one, I mean, 11 CPUs and only tapes for data storage? Even if, they would be mounted in a more accessible way - this is pure random.

---

### What is visible?

It's made up of typical PDP elements but in rather random order and mixture. There are for example:

- three [PDP-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-12) front panels (the ones with a keyboard like 'table', two of them with a screen atop)
- four boxes that seem like PDP-8f, but edited (the black/orange boxes).
- four boxes that may be based on a [PDP-11/04](http://www.pdp-11.nl/pdp11-04/pdp11-04startpage.html) or 11/34 with programmers console (or PDP-8a) but quite heavy edited (the ones with a black front and a keypad to the right).
- three [TU56 dual DECtape](http://www.pdp-11.nl/peripherals/tape/tu56-info.html)
- one (again edited) [TU-60 cassette drive](http://www.pdp-11.nl/peripherals/tape/tu60-info.html) (top of second last rack), which is interesting, as it's a rather rare device.
- The grey boxes with cables seem to be either I/O interfaces for some process/lab control, Or maybe some terminal interface - I'm not really remember any name here.

Long story short, it's most definite made to represent a DEC(ish) machine, but its parts do not make much sense. The game designer took (or found) some pictures edited (or recreated) them and used the result to 'build' the setup.

---

### Bonus Content:

There are some oscilloscopes on the right side which look much like classic Tektronics. The lower one might be a [555](https://w140.com/tekwiki/wiki/555) or 556. The one above *might* be a [564](https://w140.com/tekwiki/wiki/564). Again both are rather edited. The 555/6 should have a rather bulky power supply  below. The [cart](https://w140.com/tekwiki/wiki/555#/media/File:Wellenkino_555.jpg) holding them is again heavy edited, but rather true to the design of carts supplied by Tektronics.

Looking close, I start to appreciate the time the artist did spend to model these items in a way capturing the essence. Would be interesting (although not really RC.SE related) to see the whole setup. Maybe add a wider picture?

In addition, scopes are not exactly a to be found in a computing room. At least not a setup that expensive. Laboratory computers were usually lower end configurations - their main point was still about having budget for a computer after paying for all basic equipment to run the shop :))

Comment: And that color scheme is recognizable...

Comment: Now for extra credit identify the 'scopes on the rack at the right ... They look like Tek to me ...

Comment: @davidbak Here you go ... :))

Comment: Oscilloscopes might not usually be found in computing rooms, but low-end PDPs were commonly found in scientific/engineering contexts as data acquisition processors.  So finding a PDP or two and a stack of oscilloscopes together might not be as incongruous as you think.

Comment: In-game, these all appear inside what's supposed to be some sort of physics lab, so...

Comment: Is the TU56 *paper* tape or *magnetic* tape? I honestly can't tell from the picture.

Comment: Re, "...and only tapes for storage." OK, the CPU:Tape ratio may be all wrong, but those aren't just "tapes", they look like DECtapes. A DECtape was almost as good as a floppy. I don't recall ever using one, but I'm sure that I've walked past PDP-11 racks that had one or two dual DECtape units and no hard disk. They would have been doing some special job in a lab or in a machine room (i.e., _not_ somebody's work station.)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Magnetic-just follow the link given.

Comment: In the context of the game, though it takes place in the present day (2019), the Bureau is restricted to using 60s-era technology because their head office is supernaturally hostile to anything newer (staff have to leave their mobile phones outside for fear of exploding, for instance.) The PDP series is pretty iconic for that era of computing, so there's plenty of these visually inspired models around the game to help cement the portrayal of their tech level.

Comment: 11 CPUs and only tape? Sounds like the old phone company hardware. Massive redundant reliability but everything is stored in battery-backed memory with periodic tape dumps.

Comment: Game developers don't just reuse props to speed up development. They also do so for performance. Having less unique objects in a scene saves GPU RAM and when they are all visible at once, you can save some GPU cycles through [instanced rendering](http://www.ogldev.org/www/tutorial33/tutorial33.html).

Comment: This is the kind of answer that makes SE so outstanding. Thanks!

Comment: In these times finding a rack of oscilloscopes around a *broken* computer being fixed by specialists sent by the manufacturer wasn't that uncommon.

Answer (score 19):

As @Raffzahn answers, this is probably a concocted image made to look like various real DEC setups. The attached image is of a PDP-12. You can see the heavy tilt towards DECtapes. You also see an object in the lower image that might be an oscilloscope.

[image]

(Image taken from Ed Thelens [great site](http://ed-thelen.org/comp-hist/))

Comment: Ah, so it did come in orange as well? The only picture Wikipedia has shows bright green...

Comment: PDP-8s also came in the same orange colour

Comment: From what I recall, the -8 and the -12 are very similar machines.

Comment: The -12 looks like it was derived from the -8 and the LINC.  I know nothing about the LINC,  but I figure it's about Lincoln Laboratories.  I remember LINCtape inspired DECtape.

Comment: So you could get rack-mount DECtape holders? I guess it's convenient and it would otherwise have been a blank panel cover anyway ... maybe the DEC salesman threw it in as a freebie if your order was large enough ...

Answer (score 3):

The question has already been answered, but as the color scheme topic came up in the contents, I'd like to add some pictures from the [technikum29](https://www.technikum29.de/de/rechnertechnik/wissenschaftliche-rechner.php) museum, with all three color schemes (orange, green, blue). Images are Creative Commons (CC BY-NC 4.0) licensed.

All of those PDPs can be seen there (and are in working order, I have used some of them).

### Classic PDP-8

[image: Classic PDP-8]

### PDP-8/I

[image]

Used integrated circuits (74xx series), hence "I". Tape containers are also available in orange (I've seen some), but these probably came from the other PDPs.

### PDP-12

[image]

[image]

"Lab" computer, PDP-8 compatible.